# Help to understand the fundamental equation of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

The fundamental equation of thermodynamics states that $\mathrm dG = V\,\mathrm dp-S\,\mathrm dT$. I am having difficulty understanding this equation. The Wikipedia page for Gibbs free energy says:

> … is a thermodynamic potential that can be used to calculate the maximum of reversible work that may be performed by a thermodynamic system at a constant temperature and pressure (isothermal, isobaric).

Isn't this in direct contradiction to the fundamental equation of thermodynamics? If you have constant pressure and constant temperature, then $\mathrm dp$ and $\mathrm dT $ are both equal to $0$, so $\mathrm dG = 0$?

What am I not understanding?

Comment: You don't have any issue with thermodynamics, just with article...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The form of the equation you wrote is for the case of pure substance or mixture of constant composition.  Otherwise, there are additional terms involving the chemical potentials of the various species times the change in the number of moles of each species.